# Laravel 7 jQuery UI datepicker: Uncaught TypeError: $(…).datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datepicker

I'd like to add a **jQuery UI datepicker** field to a form in a laravel 7 app, but I always get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function.

I tried to use the source code example from [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

I read at least a dozen different posts on how to fix this, tried all of them without luck in my case.

My feeling is that my laravel app (maybe in app.js?) already loads one of the scripts or maybe a different version of a the same script (maybe jQuery?) used also by the datepicker and this causes the issue. Unfortunately being new to Laravel, I'm not sure how to solve this. Please see below some code samples and let me know, if you have any suggestions. Many thanks!

App layout file header:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
```

View file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<form action="" method="post" action="/tour/{id}">
    <!-- CROSS Site Request Forgery Protection -->
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date</label><br>
        <input id="datepicker" type="text" />
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script> 
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well here you are calling jquery twice actually. one in app js file and other from the cdn. you need not to call the cdn. and as you are using `defer` attribute in app js and another version of jquery, both are conflicting and thus datepicker is not a function. you can simply remove `defer` attribute and the extra cdn call.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Just for my education: how should I have known that I'm already calling jQuery from app.js and which version? This file was generated by the laravel framework for me. thanks!

Comment: this app js calls all dependencies through package.json file. you can check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#writing-javascript) in official doc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code perfectly works in my local installation.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Try to remove app.js and check whether your libraries are getting conflict.

If not, open your insepect element and check if you have an active internet connection and jquery ui is loaded (Refer pic 2)

[image]

[image]